# How to debug Python endpoint: works in Thunder Client but not in Python script

Tags: python, rest, debugging, integration-testing, csrf-token

I don't know where I am going wrong. This endpoint is working fine on Thunder client but not in python even though the body that is passed is also same and the headers as well.

To be sure that the body is correct I printed the data in the terminal and pasted it into the body of the thunder client.

I also double checked the token that I am passing in SC_CSRF_TOKEN is correct or not.

To get the SC_CSRF_TOKEN login to https://www.smallcase.com/ and then go to the inspect element and check the requested headers of the routes

```
def get_sc_stock_data(stock):
    print(f"Fetching stock data of {stock}")
    url=f"https://api.smallcase.com/market/search?text={stock}"
    responce=requests.get(url)
    responce=responce.json()
    res=responce['data']['searchResults']
    if(len(res)<=0):
        print("stock data not found in smallcase")
        return
    elif(len(res)==1):
        return responce['data']['searchResults'][0]
    else:
        for i in res:
            if(i['stock']['info']['ticker']==stock):
                return i

def get_stock_close_prices(stocks):
    print("Generating the close prices of basket's stocks")
    res = {'count': 0, 'total': 0}
    for stock in stocks:
        stock=stock.upper()
        try:
            st = yf.Ticker(stock+'.NS')
            price = st.history(period='1d').Close.iloc[0]
            res[stock] = price
            res['count'] += 1
            res['total'] += price
        except IndexError:
            print(f"No historical data available for {stock}")
            res[stock] = None
    return res

def convert_to_sc_format(stocks, name, desc):
    print("Generating smallcase basket")
    prices = get_stock_close_prices(stocks)
    total = prices['total']
    constituents = []
    tickers = []
    
    for stock in stocks:
        stock = stock.upper()
        data = get_sc_stock_data(stock)
        if not data:
            continue
        ticker = data['stock']['info']['ticker']
        temp = {
            "sid": data['sid'],
            "shares": 1,
            "locked": False,
            "weight": prices[ticker] / total,
            "sidInfo": {
                "name": data['stock']['info']['name'],
                "sector": data['stock']['info']['sector'],
                "ticker": ticker
            }
        }
        tickers.append(ticker)
        constituents.append(temp)
    
    res = {
        "did": None,
        "scid": None,
        "source": 'CREATED',
        "constituents": constituents,
        "segments": [
            {
                "label": "New Segment",
                "constituents": tickers
            }
        ],
        "compositionScheme": "WEIGHTS",
        "info": {
            "name": name,
            "shortDescription": desc,
            "tier": None
        },
        "stats": {
            "initialValue": total
        }
    }
    res=json.dumps(res,indent=2)
    return res

def post_basket_to_sm(stocks,name,desc):
    data=convert_to_sc_format(stocks,name,desc)
    print(data)
    
    url='https://api.smallcase.com/user/sc/drafts/save'

    headers = {
        'X-Csrf-Token': SC_CSRF_TOKEN,
    }
    res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    return res.json()
stocks=['dlf','ongc']
data1=post_basket_to_sm(stocks,'t2','t2')
print(data1)
```

I tried to use the json.dumps() as without that it was showing:

```
{'success': False, 'errors': \['Invalid token'\], 'data': None}
```

I also tried to export this data into a new json file and then import it back to the function

**Expected output**

```
{
"success": true,
"errors": null,
"data": {
"did": ".......",
"scid": "......."
}
}
```

**Output**

```
{'data': 'Please mail us at tech@smallcase.com. Mistake is on our side!'}
```

Comment: Why do you do `res=json.dumps(res,indent=2)` and then pass this to `json=`? Try to comment-out this line

Comment: I did try that too but in that case the response was coming {'success': False, 'errors': ['Invalid token'], 'data': None}

Comment: Then your `X-Csrf-Token` is invalid.

Comment: yes i thought the same but thats also correct and if the token was incorrect then the response would be {'success': False, 'errors': ['Invalid token'], 'data': None} but its coming {'data': 'Please mail us at tech@smallcase.com. Mistake is on our side!'}